# I want to realize Popen-code from Windows to Linux:

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I want to realize this code from Windows to Linux:

```
a=subprocess.Popen(['python.exe','hello.py'])
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, using subprocess.Popen to make linux command line call? I'm getting "\[Errno 2\] No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835400/python-using-subprocess-popen-to-make-linux-command-line-call-im-getting-er)

Comment: `multiprocessing` completely removes the system-specific kinks. Or just `import` the script if running it as a separate process is not central to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues. First, `python.exe` is called simply `python` in Linux, and second the python executable does not live in the current directory but somewhere in the system path. To have Linux look for `python` in the path, you can either let Popen use a shell:

```
a=subprocess.Popen(['python','hello.py'], shell=True)
```

or you can use the `env` program to find it:

```
a=subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/env', 'python','hello.py'])
```

As a third option, you could use the Linux [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) method to start the `hello.py` script, and let Windows file associations run `hello.py` in the python interpreter, by doing three things:

1. Make the first line of hello.py to be `#!/usr/bin/env python`
2. Mark the file hello.py as executable in Linux by doing `chmod a+x hello.py`.
3. Run the `hello.py` script in a shell

   `a=subprocess.Popen('hello.py', shell=True)`

This will make the script work in the same way both in Windows and in Linux.

Please be careful about the shebang line: `hello.py` must be saved with the UNIX line-ending convention, otherwise you get a vague 'python not found' error. This is caused by the extra '\n' added by the Windows editor, letting the shell look for a file named `'python\n'`--which of course does not exist. You can convert `hello.py` to UNIX line endings using the `dos2unix` tool. All respectable file editors will preserve the line endings once set to UNIX.