# How to execute a python file in another and then close after set time

Tags: python

For some code that I am making, I need to execute one python file midway through another and then terminate it after a set amount of time. From what I have read and tried, running the file as a module is not the way to go as I can not stop it after the elapsed time. (It needs to be terminated or else it will be waiting for an input indefinitely). What would be the way to go with this?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show minimum effort in solving the issue and then ask about a specific problem in an attempted solution. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What should happen if the other code is in the middle of doing something when the time expires? What if, for example, it has a file open?

Comment: For what I have tried so far is using the OS module and importing the file in as a module, I have also looked at multiprocessing in the first python script but that was not working for me as well as some other modules such as pytimedinput but that was not suitable as I am using an NFC reader and that did not work with that solution.

Comment: And for what would happen, the script that needs to be opened will be checking if a card is at the NFC reader and if it saves the content to a text file, the chances in the use case of this happening are low but if it did then the code would be running in a loop and would be reactivated soon so it would not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like subprocess is what you need:

```
import subprocess
import time

start = time.time()
TIME_TO_WAIT = 60
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "otherScript.py"])

while True:
    if (time.time() - start) < TIME_TO_WAIT:
        cleanup(process)
        break
```

In cleanup, you close open files or whatever else you may need to do for a clean exit and then finally call

```
process.terminate()
```

or

```
process.kill()
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: When running it I get this error: `process = subprocess.pOpen(["python", "test2.py"])
AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'pOpen'`

Comment: Typo, should be ```subprocess.Popen(...)```. Will fix the answer.

Comment: It was working fine on windows but when trying it on my raspberry pi where the code is going to be running, it will not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm... couple of questions: are you sure python is installed on your pi? If so, maybe the command is ```python3``` instead of ```python``` (there are ways to alias it, but you can check to see if that's the problem first). Then you might also need to check if it's a problem with where you're running the script from and where the subprocess' script is located relative to it. Lastly, could be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142480/i-want-to-realize-popen-code-from-windows-to-linux?noredirect=1&lq=1 . But that's all I can think of right now.

Comment: I have tried python3 in the call and making it an executable file but that did not work, would there be a way to have the code in one script, call it and terminate it after a set amount of time?

Comment: Do you mean just have all of the code you want to execute in a single script? Or have only two scripts (as opposed to 2+ scripts)?

Comment: In a single script if that would work. But I am open to any way that allows it to timeout and stops it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought you meant. BUT! That's a separate question, so you'll probably want to start a new question on SO.